# How to compile the latest version of the command-line video download tool - cclive

Tags: installation, command-line, compiling

`cclive` is a tool for downloading media from YouTube and similar websites.

I am trying to compile the latest version of `cclive` but cannot compile the first step [libquvi](http://quvi.sourceforge.net/)

I am getting the following error when I do ...

```
> sudo sh autogen.sh 
Generate configuration files...
configure.ac:92: warning: macro `AM_ICONV' not found in library
configure.ac:36: warning: AC_LANG_CONFTEST: no AC_LANG_SOURCE call detected in body
...
configure.ac:92: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_ICONV
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/local/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

[Full Output](http://pastebin.com/s2TEvMFe)

perhaps I am missing some dependencies or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Compile libquvi

Ok,  to compile libquvi you will need to do the following:

Download the  latest version of quvi from http://quvi.sourceforge.net

Install some necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libpcre++-dev libtolua++5.1-dev
```

Now extract the package you have downloaded

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvf <package name>
cd quvi-<version>
```

now run .configure

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-nsfw --enable-broken
```

Now compile and install the deb

```
make
sudo checkinstall -D
```

i.e. checkinstall will guide you through the create deb and install process - just hit enter to all the questions.

### Compile cclive

Ok,  to compile cclive you will need to do the following:

Download the  latest version of cclive from http://cclive.googlecode.com

Install some necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
```

Now extract the package you have downloaded

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xvf <package name>
cd cclive-<version>
```

now run .configure

```
./configure
```

Now compile and install the deb

```
make
sudo checkinstall -D
```